# Jenkins pipeline to abort based on the output of ealier stage

Tags: shell, jenkins, devops, jenkins-groovy, groovyshell

**Am comparing two files if i get the out put as "Yes" jenkins pipeline should continue if i get output as "No" jenkins pipeline should return error**

the command i have used to compare 2 files is mentioned below. I have placed this command in **test.sh** file in /jenkins location

`test "$(comm -23 <(sort -u /jenkins/OUTPUT1.txt) <(sort -u /jenkins/OUTPUT2.txt) | wc -l)" = "$(cat /jenkins/OUTPUT2.txt | wc -l)" && echo Yes || echo No`

The jenkins pipeline i used is

````
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
          result = sh(script: 'bash /jenkins/test.sh', returnStdout: true)
        }
    stages {
      stage('command') {
        steps {
          script {
                    if (result == '${env.result}') {
                        result = Yes
                        echo "conditions are met"
                    } else if (result == '${env.result}') {
                        result = No
                        error('Conditions are not met - build aborted')
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}```

Please suggest me a correct pipeline script for this condition
````

Comment: Just remove all your code, remove `&& echo yes || echo No` from your script, and do `script { sh 'bash test.sh' }`. Or `exit 1` when `test` exits with non-zero.

Comment: @KamilCuk can you please suggest a command like " if it gives exit 1 out put it should also echo **Conditions are not met** " how to write a command for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a script that properly exits with nonzero exit status in case of failure:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(comm -23 <(sort -u /jenkins/OUTPUT1.txt) <(sort -u /jenkins/OUTPUT2.txt) | wc -l)
shouldbe=$(wc -l < /jenkins/OUTPUT2.txt)
if [[ "$var" != "$shouldbe" ]]; the
      echo "Och noooo!"
      exit 1
else 
      echo "Yes!"
fi
```

Then just call the script:

```
script {
    sh 'bash ./yourscript.sh'
 }
```

Jenkins checks if each script is successful (i.e. has zero exit status). A non-zero exit status means failure.